# Is it possible to have a proxy server on a shared IP-address?

Tags: proxy, ip

Does it work if you enters the domain of the server instead of the IP-address or do you need to have a dedicated IP-address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you're proxying. For HTTP proxies, most browsers I've run into will accept a domain-name in the proxy fields, which means that dynamic IP addresses should be supported.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow the question.  If the question is whether it's possible to run multiple instances of a proxy (assuming http/ftp) server on a single IP, yes - use a different port for each instance.

If the question is whether you can use a fqdn to define a proxy server, yes - most (all?) browsers support fqdn for proxy server lookup.

If you want to specify multiple proxy servers, you can use round robin DNS (not very deterministic) or you can use a [PAC file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config).